# Gitlab-ci and cmake : different jobs for pre-build and build

Tags: cmake, gitlab-ci

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, I want to separate my cmake pre-build job and my build job.
For this, I tried to use `cache` but it seems that my pre-build folder is not passed to my build job.

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: ubuntu:22.04
before_script:
 - apt update
 - apt install cmake ninja-build gcc-arm-none-eabi -y

stages:
- build

pre-build:
  stage: build
  script:
   - cmake --preset=Release
  cache:
    paths:
      - build/Release
    policy: push

build:
  stage: build
  script:
   - cmake --build build/Release
  cache:
    paths:
      - build/V2_Release
    policy: pull
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```yaml
image: ubuntu:22.04
before_script:
 - apt update
 - apt install cmake ninja-build gcc-arm-none-eabi -y

stages:
  - pre-build
  - build

pre-build:
  stage: pre-build
  script:
   - cmake --preset=Release
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/V2_Release
    expire_in: 5 mins

build:
  stage: build
  script:
   - cmake --build build/Release
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/Release/main.bin
```